# How do I specify the path for Devkit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devkit

I'm here on Windows 7 x64 and am trying to install Ruby on Rails from scratch. I just installed the `RubyInstaller 1.9.3-p429` and now just ran the `DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx`. After doing `ruby dk.rb install --force`. I tried to test if it's setup correctly but run into:

```
c:\DevKit>gem install RedCloth --platform=ruby
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
The system cannot find the path specified.
ERROR:  Error installing RedCloth:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lc... no
creating Makefile


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9/ext/redcloth_scan/gem_make.out
```

And this happens to all gems that need the Devkit. I guess I have to set the path specified but I have no idea what that means. How do I do that or what's the real problem here?

P.S.

A little bit of background. I did have RailsInstaller installed but I was getting the same error so I deleted everything. I also had NodeJs installed as well but deleted that too. I erased the PATH variables completely to start from scratch.

**UPDATE**

Trying the RailsInstaller gives me this error:

```
$ gem install json -v 1.8.0
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
The system cannot find the path specified.
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile


Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 10):

I hate to bump an old thread, but I wish to add to the answers just in case someone else comes by (likely as this is at the top of a Google search for a "Devkit PATH error").

After extracting the DevKit into a permanent directory and after you've navigated to the install folder within your shell and entered the "ruby dk.rb init" command, make sure you actually do the next step and **install** the devkit. After the init command, run "ruby dk.rb install" and that should fix many similar problems.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!! This process is not so intuitive for us windows users because we assume once it has been installed, it is done.

Comment: ie/  "ruby c:\devkit\dk.rb init"

Comment: i.e., follow the official directions that another developer took the time to clearly write: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Comment: yep, this is still how you fix the ruby devkit installation on windows 10. (kind of baffling that the official docs bury this info)

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the Devkit/bin directory in your environment path.  First, find out where Devkit was installed. For this example, we'll presume it's at `C:\Devkit`.

Next open your Advanced System Settings (accessible under MyComputer => Properties), and click the Environment Variables button.  Under the 'user variables' section, edit the 'Path' entry to include `C:\Devkit\bin`.  Note that this entry is semicolon delimited so you'll need to add a trailing (or prepending) semicolon to this string.

Comment: Under my User Variables I put `Path` and inside of it `C:\Devkit\bin;` but still get the same error :(. I tried even to put it in my `Path` on my System variables but no luck.

Comment: @LearningRoR: You need to open a new terminal console to see the effect of changing the path - it won't fix consoles that are already open.  Also, have you confirmed that `C:Devkit` is where it was installed?

Comment: Yeah I restarted the computer and my Devkit is in c:\Devkit. I'm going to reinstall everything.

Comment: Yeah, still no good. Even with a reinstall of RubyInstaller and the Devkit.

Comment: I also just tried the RailsInstaller again but it throws me the same errors.

Comment: @LearningRoR: Can you post the contents of the output file mentioned in the error?

Comment: @LearningRoR: This is the friendly console error - the actual error is in `c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out`.  Can you post the contents of this file (particularly the part where the error begins).

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the excact same problem when I tried to install Cucumber until I tried using the `--verbose` parameter. For some reasons this worked out for me but I cannot really explain why. I am not considering it as a solution but it is worth a try.

Comment: I do not understand why this worked, but it did. That is possibly the last thing I would have ever tried, and yet, there it is.

Comment: It's really strange i tried almost everything , and --verbose flag was my last try before i could actually give up and it worked

Answer (score 1):

The best that has worked for me always in these errors is: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#wiki-gems_fails_comspec_autorun

If you installed the devkit as per standard guidelines on https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit#installation-instructions, then it's not the Devkit path but the incorrect Autorun regex key OR the incorrect command processor set by other tools that interferes with ruby gem installations. Give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, Windows 8 x64, Ruby 2.2.3.

I tried everything from many posts and many answers but only this worked for me: Deleting old devkits and installing again.

I got it working after these steps:

1. Delete every folder you have ever installed devkit
2. Install (x64 - 64bits only) DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
3. Execute and install somewhere without spaces or anything on the path (I did c:\devkit)
4. Go to your system environments and add to the path c:\devkit and c:\devkit\bin
5. Open a CMD prompt as an admin, go to c:\devkit and type:

   `ruby dk.rb init
   ruby dk.rb install --force`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

That details a couple scenarios that can cause this problem. Just in case the link dies, though. The first is where your COMSPEC system variable no longer has a full path to cmd.exe.  The second is where some kind of autorun is in the registry--this is where you check:

```
REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /s
REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /s
REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Command Processor" /s
REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Command Processor" /s
```

And if you see any autoruns you delete them with something like:

```
REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
```